# How can I keep poetry and commitizen versions synced?

Tags: python, python-poetry, commitizen

I have a `pyproject.toml` with

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_conventional_commits"
version = "0.1.0"
```

I add a new feature and commit with commit message

```
feat: add parameter for new feature
```

**That's one commit.**

Then I call

```
commitizen bump
```

Commitizen will recognize a minor version increase, update my `pyproject.toml`, and commit again with the updated `pyproject.toml` and a tag `0.2.0`.

**That's a second commit.**

But now my `pyproject.toml` is "out of whack" (assuming I want my build version in sync with my git tags).

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_conventional_commits"
version = "0.2.0"
```

I'm two commits in, one tagged, and things still aren't quite right. Is there workflow to keep everything aligned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

refer to [support-for-pep621](https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/faq/#support-for-pep621) and [version_files](https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/bump/#version_files)

you can add "pyproject.toml:^version" to pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.commitizen]
version_files = [
    "pyproject.toml:^version"
]
```

Comment: Just to add, ensure that the project version and commitizen version are in sync before  bumping (you can do this manually) and this should be a one-time thing. If not in sync prior to bump, bump(s) won't update project version