# How can I reference var from section into another section in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml, commitizen

Hello I am building a pyproject object and I have the following two sections

```
[tool.poetry]
version = "0.1.0"

[tool.commitizen]
version = "0.1.0"
```

As you can see poetry uses the version in its section and commitizen in its section, the question is how to can I set only one version and share between sections?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The [TOML](https://toml.io) syntax doesn't support this. (https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/829)

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly I do with

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "aipose"
version = "1.0.0"

[tool.commitizen]
version = "1.0.0"
version_files = [
    "pyproject.toml:^version"
]
tag_format = "$version"
```

You can check a complete use with github actions in this repository: https://github.com/Tlaloc-Es/aipose/

Source:

- [How can I keep poetry and commitizen versions synced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74923308/how-can-i-keep-poetry-and-commitizen-versions-synced)